# What's the difference between default_transport & content_filter in Postfix

Tags: postfix

Postfix has two options which to me appear to do the same thing: `default_transport` and `content_filter`.

https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#default_transport
https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#content_filter

For example I have these this processes setup in `master.cf`

```
my_custom_smtp_client            unix  -       -       n       -       -    smtp
```

I can then use either one of these options in a `smtpd` process and it achieves the same result:

```
-o content_filter=my_custom_smtp_client
```

or

```
-o default_transport=my_custom_smtp_client
```

Is it wrong? Or is it just best practice to use one over the other depending on the context or use case?